# Get Keys With Value From Inside Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an `object` like this:

```
trueOptions = {
  trueOption1 : true,
  trueOption2 : true,
  trueOption3 : false,
  trueOption4 : false,
  trueOption5 : true
}
```

I want to get the `keys` for the `items` with `true` `values` from inside the `object`.

How can I get these `items`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate through the keys of an object and check their values?

Comment: Just to be clear; do you want the keys whose corresponding value is true? Like `['trueOption1', 'trueOption2', 'trueOption5']` in your example?

Comment: This is not a React question, but a javascript question.

Comment: @Philip Yes, that exactly what i want. Sorry but my english is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `map` on [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const options = {
     trueOption1: true,
     trueOption2: true,
     trueOption3: false,
     trueOption4: false,
     trueOption5: true
  }

const trueOptions = Object.entries(options).filter(option=>option[1]).map(option=>option[0])

console.log(trueOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1***

See [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const options =  {option1: true,option2: true,option3: false,option4: false,option5: true}

// Trues.
const trues = obj => Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => value).map(([key]) => key)

// Output.
const output = trues(options)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

***Option 2***

See [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const options =  {option1: true,option2: true,option3: false,option4: false,option5: true}

// Trues.
const trues = obj => Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => v || undefined)))

// Output.
const output = trues(options)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through each key and then use `array#filter` to filter out keys whose value is `true`.

```js
const trueOptions = { trueOption1 : true, trueOption2 : true, trueOption3 : false, trueOption4 : false, trueOption5 : true },
      result = Object.keys(trueOptions).filter(k => trueOptions[k]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(trueOptions).forEach(d=>{if(trueOptions[d] != true){delete trueOptions[d];}})

Object.keys(trueOptions)
```

Comment: Explain you answer in details